# Difference between InsertOneModel vs InsertOneAsyn

Tags: c#, mongodb

I use methods available with the collection:

```
collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
```

But collection.InsertOneModel() does not exist.

What is the difference between InsertOneAsync vs InsertOneModel?
When I should use InsertOneModel?
How does InsertOneModel know in which collection I want the document to be inserted?

Comment: Are you sure you looked at the right docs? `InsertOneModel` is from the java api, c# has `InsertOneModel<TDocument>`. https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_InsertOneModel_1.htm

Comment: Actually, it does: [link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master/src/MongoDB.Driver)

Comment: Still dont see the Class, the filename is InsertOneModel but the class inside is the generic type. This is what I can see: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/InsertOneModel.cs

Comment: hmmm ur right! so what is the use and in which collection it store? I did a test with my existing code it works but can see in any of my collections...

Comment: Not sure what is your confusion here, InsertOne will insert one object/row in the collection. The collection will be the one which your object collection is referring too. InsertOneAsync is just the async version of the sync method.

Comment: I'm ok with InsertOne and InsertOneAsync, i'm confused with the InsertOneModel() class

Comment: Ahh...that class seems to be for use in the bulk write api, look at the documentation, scroll to Bulk Write section: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/getting_started/quick_tour/

Comment: Omg ! That's what i was looking for ! Thx !!